# Angular Karma: await fixture.whenStable always times out after upgrade from Angular v8 to v12

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have some unit tests for a component that uses reactive forms.

In the tests, I will patch values on the form, and then the unit test will test what I expect from various form `valueChanges` subscriptions.

So that the test waits for the `valueChanges` to execute, I always used the following after the `patch`:

```
fixture.detectChanges();
await fixture.whenStable();
```

and this always worked fine.

After my upgrade (went from v8 to v12), all tests time out when I have the `await fixture.whenStable()`.

Ie I get:

```
    Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
    error properties: Object({ originalStack: 'Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
            at new ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-error.js:92:33)
```

Of course, if I remove the  `await fixture.whenStable();` the test no longer works, as when I try and access the properties set is the form `valueChanges` they are not set.

Why would the `await fixture.whenStable()` now seem to hang?

Comment: Have you tried using `waitForAsync` or `fakeAsync` and `tick`? I doubt they could solve your issue but it maybe worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried every combination, but it just does not  wait or the valueChanges to fire without the await fixture.whenStable().

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this today, I think I found the problem (in my case).

I had a `setTimeout` in the components `ngAfterViewInit()` which was not being cleared. Infact having the setTimeout at all was a bug, it was only need to go off once, so should have been a `setInterval`. I did have some problems with the `ngAfterViewInit` so I already had

```
spyOn(component, 'ngAfterViewInit').and.callFake(() => { });
```

as the code in the timer was not that important (just turing animations on/off), so still not 100% sure why a change in the real `ngAfterViewInit` made a difference... and yet it did, my `await fixture.whenStable();` no longer hangs, and the test now waits for the forms `valueChanges`.